# displaying a decimal number in c# console with double

Tags: c#, console, double, decimal

hello, here is my code

```
    double d = 8.0;
    b = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine(d+b);
```

sample input/output

1. input 8   /output 16
2. input 8,0 /output 16
3. input 8.0 /output 88

how can i output a 16.0 in case 1 and 2?
and 2nd question, how can i tell c# that 8.0 is an 8 instead of 80?

i can do

```
    double value=d+b;
    Console.WriteLine(value.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB")));
```

but that doesnt change that that the 8.0 is interpreted as a 80,
it also doesnt change the display of 16

my question is how can i display a .0 or a ,0 anytime the number is not actually a decimal.

Comment: See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings

Comment: When you use convert function it uses your default CultureInfo (some use , as a dot and some treat . as a dot) deneds on what your computer is defining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1**

You need to:

1. Replace all commas with a period to normalise the decimal separator to ".".
2. You need to pass a `IFormatProvider` to your call to `ToDouble` to control how it parses the number.  Passing `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is sufficient because it treats "." as a decimal separator.

**Question 2**

As commented by @jdweng you need to use a format string to control the output. 
 The `$"{result:0.00}"` expression is what's doing the magic here: this is an [interpolated string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated), which essentially takes whatever is stored in `result` and applies the `0:00` format string to it, which limits the output to two decimal places.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var d = 8.0D;
        var userInput = "8,0";
        userInput = userInput.Replace(',', '.');
        var b = Convert.ToDouble(userInput, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var result = d + b;
        var formattedOutput = $"{result:0.00}";
        Console.WriteLine(formattedOutput);
    }
}
```